# Laravel one to many relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-3

I'm building an app in Laravel in which Users have a Role.

I've set up the User model with `return $this->belongs_to('Role')` and the Role model with `return $this->has_many('User')` and the users database table has the column role_id.

My question is on reading, and also updating the Role through the User model. The below code is what I've been trying but so far no luck:

Controller

```
return View::make('admin.users.index')->with('users', User::paginate(50));
// Also tried User::with('role')->paginate(50) which doesn't help
```

View

```
@foreach($users->results as $user)

    {{ $user->role->role }} // Trying to get property of non-object
    {{ $user->role()->role }} // Undefined property

    {{ var_dump($user->role) }}

    // Outputs
    object(Role)#39 (5) {
        ["attributes"]=>
            array(4) {
                ["id"]=> string(1) "2"
                ["role"]=> string(4) "User"
                ["created_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
            }
        ["original"]=>
            array(4) {
                ["id"]=> string(1) "2"
                ["role"]=> string(4) "User"
                ["created_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
            }
        ["relationships"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
        ["exists"]=> bool(true)
        ["includes"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
    }

@endforeach
```

And updating is a similar story - `$user->role = Input::get('role')` doesn't work either.

I'm obviously missing something here, could anybody show me the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://vespakoen.github.com/authority-laravel/

It is an ACL Authority bundle for laravel. There an user can has 1 to n roles, so it uses `this->has_many_and_belongs_to`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I'm specifically looking for how to work with a one to many relationship rather than a many to many

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, role returns an array, so you have to access it like an array

the correct way to access it would be

$user->role[0]->id